# Eclipse: g++: command not found

Tags: windows, eclipse, c++, g++

I have installed Eclipse via System Workbench for STM32.
Meaning I have an icon now named System Workbench for STM32, and when I open it Eclipse opens.

With that IDE I can successfully create programs for the microicontroller STM32.

However, I want to make unit tests which I can run on a PC, and while after installing google test/mock I get the error:

/usr/bin/sh: g++: command not found

I get the same problem when I make a generic C++ project (either with GNU auto toolchain or using a G++ Cross compiler, or using the default C++ Hello World project).

Also, I do not see an Includes folder.

However, when I check in Help/About Eclipse, I see that Eclipse CDT is installed (version 9.2.1.201704050...)

How can I compile C++ application for PC only? Should I install something more, and from where/how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen when gcc is not installed or not configured correctly.

Do a

```
sudo apt update
```

And also a

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

If this works, great!

Comment: I don't have Linux or Unix (so sudo does not work).

Comment: The directory /usr/bin exists for Unix and Unix like operating systems. Are you sure you've downloaded eclipse for your operating system?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer; guess I loaded it for the wrong one; now it seems good. I accept your answer since it lead to the solution.